# View not finding action in controller in Asp.Net core 3

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core

I'm trying to call the action `FileUploadAsync` from the view. The refresh button that just calls the Index action is working perfectly. The upload button on the view is returning 404 not found... can't think of a reason why.

Controller:

```
[Area("Admin")]
public class MetricController : Controller
{
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var allBlobs = await _azureBlobService.ListAsync();
        return View(allBlobs);
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> FileUploadAsync()
    {
        var request = await HttpContext.Request.ReadFormAsync();
        if (request.Files == null)
        {
            return BadRequest("files not uploaded");
        }

        var files = request.Files;
        if (files.Count == 0)
        {
            return BadRequest("files empty");
        }

        await _azureBlobService.UploadAsync(files);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

View:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
        <span>Select Files</span><input type="file" id="file" name="selectFiles" class="upload" onchange="DisplayFilesToUpload()" multiple />
    </div>
    <p id="FilesToUpload"></p>
    @if (Model != null && Model.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <div>
                <p class="text-secondary">@item</p>
            </div>
        }
    }
    <a asp-area="Admin" asp-controller="Metric" asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm">
        Refresh
    </a>
    <a asp-area="Admin" asp-controller="Metric" asp-action="FileUploadAsync" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm">
        Upload
    </a>
    <a asp-action="DeleteAll" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm">
        Delete All
    </a>
    @section scripts{
        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/metrics.js"></script>
    }
</div>
```

**Edit:**
On `Startup.cs` the routing is deffined as follows

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{area=Agent}/{controller=Article}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
```

So this sholudn't be the issue...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54932721/asp-net-core-area-routing-to-api-controller-not-working

Comment: Routing is properly setup in the solution @xqtr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been discussed in github:https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/8998

`Async` suffix for controller action names will be trimmed by default in asp.net core 3.0.

Prior to 3.0, the action will be routeable via `Admin/Metric/FileUploadAsync`. Link generation would require specifying the Async suffix e.g.

```
<a asp-area="Admin" asp-controller="Metric" asp-action="FileUploadAsync" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm">
    Upload
</a>
```

In 3.0, the action will be routeable via `Admin/Metric/FileUpload` and link generation would require not specifying the Async suffix.

One solution is that you could change your view code to below:

```
 <a asp-area="Admin" asp-controller="Metric" asp-action="FileUpload" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm">
    Upload
</a>
```

The other solution is that you could just disable this behavior , add below code in startup ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
   options.SuppressAsyncSuffixInActionNames = false; 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your view to this:

```html
<a asp-area="Admin" asp-controller="Metric" asp-action="FileUpload" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm">
    Upload
</a>
```

Reference: [Async suffix removal from controller action names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30#async-suffix-removal-from-controller-action-names)