# Attribute routing is not working properly in asp.net core 3.0

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1, asp.net-core-3.0, asp.net-core-routing

I was trying to migrate my application from asp.net core 2.1 to 3.0 which uses attribute routing

My Startup file's ConfigureServices and Configure methods:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.ConfigureOptions(typeof(ABCClass));
    services.AddTransient<ITagHelperComponent, XYZTagHelperComponent>();            
    services.AddMvc();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
       app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
}
```

I have replaced `services.AddMvc();` with `services.AddMvc(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false);` to disable Endpoint routing

My action method:

```
[Route("")]
[Route("Machines")]
public async Task<ViewResult> GetMachinesAsync()
{
    return View("MachineView");
}
```

First time my application loads with MachineView, but when I try to call same action method on it gives me 404 error (page can’t be found)

action call from .cshtml file:

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link"
       href="@Url.Action("GetMachinesAsync", "Machine")">
       Machines 
    </a>
</li>
```

Can you please help me out if I am missing something here, or I have done something wrong while configuring middleware for routing.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Async suffix for controller action names will be trimmed by default in asp.net core 3.0.

Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/59024733/10158551

Solution1:

Replace `GetMachinesAsync` to `GetMachines` in view.

```
<li class="nav-item">
 <a class="nav-link"
   href="@Url.Action("GetMachines", "Machine")">
   Machines 
</a>
</li>
```

Solution2:

Keep using `GetMachinesAsync`

```
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link"
   href="@Url.Action("GetMachinesAsync", "Machine")">
   Machines 
</a>
</li>
```

then  disable that behavior  in startup

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
     options.EnableEndpointRouting = false;
     options.SuppressAsyncSuffixInActionNames = false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't require `async` suffixes for action methods. So if you want to refer `GetMachinesAsync` you need to use `GetMachines`, like this.

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link"
       href="@Url.Action("GetMachines", "Machine")">
       Machines 
    </a>
</li>
```